# How to use with Facebook HTTP_REFERER (with php)

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I would like to know how I can use this method so that if someone clicks on my website through a post on Facebook, it goes to another page, using HTTP_REFERER, and if possible, have cookies so that it only goes to that page once

I need that when clicking only on Facebook the person is taken to another page instead of the home page

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to mention the "referrer" in the link itself. So if I post a link to my website on Facebook it could look like this:

```
https://example.com?referrer=facebook
```

Then at the top of the home page of my website, in PHP, I do:

```
if (($_GET["referrer"] ?? "") == "facebook") {
    header("Location: https://example.com/for_facebook.php");
    exit;
}
```

To make this permanent you can store something in the session, it that lasts long enough, or in a cookie, and react to that. So, in case of a cookie:

```
if ((($_GET["referrer"] ?? "") == "facebook") ||
    (($_COOKIE["referrer"] ?? "") == "facebook")) {
    setcookie("referrer", "facebook", 2147483647);
    header("Location: https://example.com/for_facebook.php");
    exit;
}
```

As you can see, I also added the check for the cookie in there. You can even extend this to make it work for all sites you want to link from, and it doesn't depend on the HTTP_REFERER header.

Comment: If you have cookies, I don't want the page to be shown, it goes straight to home, does this code do that?

Comment: @Segatto : Sorry, in my case I used the cookie to _always_ go to the `for_facebook.php` page, but it can be used to go only once, just change `($_COOKIE["referrer"] ?? "") == "facebook")` to `(!isset($_COOKIE["referrer"])`. In other words: Only go to the special page if the cookie isn't set yet. I must say that this is unwanted behavior, because an user might click on the back button, to check something, and then the forward button will go to a different page (unless you cache it).

Comment: @Segatto : In the end you should try an understand what the code does, so you can modify it yourself. Don't just ask what it does, and copy it if it satisfies your criteria.